# Swift - UITableViewCell jumps when updating UILabel text

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitableview, uilabel

When I update my UILabel text in my UITableViewCell like this:

```
self.label.text = "label text"
```

Everything works great....

**But** when I update my labels text from the **Struct Array** it causes the UITableView to sometimes jump when scrolling up to the top, not when scrolling down, but when I scroll towards the top...

Cannot understand why this happens....

**Struct, data is being added from the results I get from the server**

```
struct ContentStruct {
  var textLink : String? = ""
  var title : String? = ""
  var text : String? = ""
}
```

**CellForRow**

```
let postData = cellContentArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section]

cell.binData(content: postData)
```

**TableViewCell**

```
 func binData(content: ContentStruct) {
    self.titleLabel.text = content.title
    self.text.text = "yytytytyt"//text
    self.uuidLabel.text = "yhhyhyhyyh"
   }
```

**I am resizing the cell's like so:**
In the ViewDidLoad:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

And then this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let height = self.heightAtIndexPath.object(forKey: indexPath)
    if ((height) != nil) {
        return CGFloat(height as! CGFloat)
    } else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let height = cell.frame.size.height
    self.heightAtIndexPath.setObject(height, forKey: indexPath as NSCopying)
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add data source code

Comment: @WetSweater Not sure what you mean by that? tableView code? or the Struct code? I am adding data to the struct from the results I previously downloaded from my server... And then I am updating the tableViewCell normally... It's strange because it only happens on the third/fourth cell from the bottom not on any others.. it's a tiny flash which I find quite anoying

Comment: Full contents of the cellForRow method would help provide a suggestion. Are you reloading the tableView somewhere?

Comment: **Struct Array**...?

Comment: Add your UITableViewDataSource and info about cell layout. It would be helpful

Comment: @Stephen I have updated my question

Comment: @Andreas I have updated above

Comment: @WetSweater Updated with code

Answer (score 2):

I've found that jumps like that occur when your dynamic cell heights don't match with your estimated row height. Easiest fix is to have a fixed cell height, or to calculate the height individually per cell.

Comment: Yes I agree it's a lot easier to have fixed cell heights, but in this case I cannot... Give me 1 min and I'll add above how I am resizing the cell's.

Comment: But the weird things is the jump doesn't happen if I update the label with a string like this "String"....